# Python Error: django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: mysqlclient 1.3.13 or newer is required; you have 0.9.3

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to run a Django application, which requires a MySql database,
I have MySql installed and it works fine with other languages.
I'm using a virtual environment to run the Django project,
But I'm facing issues with setting up the MySql configuration with the following python libraries -
**pymysql and mysqlclient**

**Project structure -**

[image]

There seems to be a version mismatch,
**Following is the full error -**

```
(env) Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:djangocrashcourse-master aniruddhanarendraraje$ python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/env/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/djangocrashcourse-master/posts/models.py", line 5, in <module>
    class Posts(models.Model):
  File "/Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 117, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 321, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 204, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 201, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/env/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 36, in <module>
    raise ImproperlyConfigured('mysqlclient 1.3.13 or newer is required; you have %s.' % Database.__version__)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: mysqlclient 1.3.13 or newer is required; you have 0.9.3.
```

[image]

**Issue -**

`mysqlclient 1.4.4` is already installed, still the error. 
`pymysql` is of version `0.9.3`, I tried uninstalling it and running,
But it requires me to install it back.

**I've tried the following -**

```
pip uninstall pymysql
pip uninstall mysqlclient
```

1. then installing only pymysql and running
2. installing only mysqlclient and running
3. installing both pymysql and mysqlclient and running

**I'm trying to run this project for study -**
https://github.com/bradtraversy/djangocrashcourse

**Steps to check running the virtual env first and then running the manage/py file -**

```
Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:python_django aniruddhanarendraraje$ ls
djangocrashcourse-master        env                             mysite
Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:python_django aniruddhanarendraraje$ source ./env/bin/activate
(env) Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:python_django aniruddhanarendraraje$ cd djangocrashcourse-master/
(env) Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:djangocrashcourse-master aniruddhanarendraraje$ pip list
Package     Version
----------- -------
Django      2.2.4  
mysqlclient 1.4.4  
pip         19.2.3 
pytz        2019.2 
setuptools  41.2.0 
sqlparse    0.3.0  
wheel       0.33.6 
(env) Aniruddhas-MacBook-Pro:djangocrashcourse-master aniruddhanarendraraje$ python manage.py runserver
Watching for file changes with StatReloader
Exception in thread django-main-thread:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 15, in <module>
    import MySQLdb as Database
  File "/Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 18, in <module>
    from . import _mysql
ImportError: dlopen(/Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so, 2): Library not loaded: @rpath/libmysqlclient.21.dylib
  Referenced from: /Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/_mysql.cpython-37m-darwin.so
  Reason: image not found

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 926, in _bootstrap_inner
    self.run()
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.7/lib/python3.7/threading.py", line 870, in run
    self._target(*self._args, **self._kwargs)
  File "/Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 109, in inner_run
    autoreload.raise_last_exception()
  File "/Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 77, in raise_last_exception
    raise _exception[1]
  File "/Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 337, in execute
    autoreload.check_errors(django.setup)()
  File "/Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 54, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/__init__.py", line 24, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "/Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/registry.py", line 114, in populate
    app_config.import_models()
  File "/Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/apps/config.py", line 211, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "/Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/env/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/djangocrashcourse-master/posts/models.py", line 5, in <module>
    class Posts(models.Model):
  File "/Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 117, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, app_label))
  File "/Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/base.py", line 321, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "/Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/models/options.py", line 204, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "/Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/__init__.py", line 28, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "/Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 201, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "/Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 110, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "/Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/env/lib/python3.7/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1006, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 983, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 967, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 677, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 728, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/aniruddhanarendraraje/Documents/work/pocs/pythonBasics/python_django/env/lib/python3.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py", line 20, in <module>
    ) from err
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?
```

Comment: I don't get what is unclear about the error?

Comment: `mysqlclient 1.4.4`  is already installed, still the error

Comment: `mysqlclient` is the recommended package so since you can install it I would focus on getting that working and don't use `pymysql`. If you uninstall `mysqlclient` and `pymysql`, then only reinstall `mysqlclient`, what is the exact error message that you get? Even better, start a new virtual env instead of reinstalling.

Comment: if I uninstall `pymysql` and run the App, it gives me `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pymysql'` error

Comment: If you are using `mysqlclient` only then you shouldn't need to import `pymysql`. Remove the import and `pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()` if you added it.

Comment: @Alasdair After removing the `the import and pymysql.install_as_MySQLdb()` I get an error - `django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Error loading MySQLdb module.
Did you install mysqlclient?` But i can see `mysqlclient 1.4.4` when I do `pip list`

Comment: Perhaps `pip list` isn't using the same virtual env that you are running Django in. Activate the virtual env, then run `python -m pip` to install and list the packages. Then make sure you stay in the virtual env before running `python manage.py runserver`.

Comment: How can I find out which venv is pip using? I've added the steps to check and run the venv first, checking pip list and then running the App in the question.